# I tried to use NSHost and XCode didn't recognize it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nshost

I tried to add an NSHost method and XCode didn't recognize it.

Do you know why this happened?

Comment: Please post your code and the exact error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is tagged with iPhone; NSHost is not available on the iPhone.  NSHost is Mac OS X only.

Here is an alternative solution to using NSHost: [Alternatives to NSHost in iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434192/alternatives-to-nshost-in-iphone-app)

Answer (score 2):

NSHost is not supported for iPhone. Read apple's technical note

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1652/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

iPhone SDK does not support NSHost. But you can [use this alternative Objective-C custom class](http://www.bdunagan.com/2009/11/28/iphone-tip-no-nshost/) instead.