# How do I create instance of NSHost from IP address?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Apologies- i'm new to xcode/cocoa/objective-c...

I'm struggling to understand what is wrong with:

```
NSHost *host = [NSHost hostWithAddress:@"192.168.0.155"];
```

I'm receiving 2 errors"

```
No known class method for selector 'hostWithAddress:'
Receiver 'NSHost' for class message is a forward declaration
```

Could you help explain the errors and how I can achieve the simple task of creating an instance of NSHost pointing to 192.168.0.155.

Thanks

Lee

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out NSHost is not available on the iPhone! It's a shame xcode didn't highlight that for me!

[I tried to use NSHost and XCode didn't recognize it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450471/i-tried-to-use-nshost-and-xcode-didnt-recognize-it)

Thanks for your help,

Lee

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation for NSHost](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHost_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you are using exactly the right method. However from looking at your error message, it says `hostwithAddress`, the correct casing is `hostWithAddress`, so make sure there is a capital W.

Also, make sure you have `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` at the top of your .m file.

Remember, Objective-C is a case sensitive language.

Comment: Unfortunately it wasn't that simple. I copy/pasted the code but the error message doesn't allow copy/paste so i retyped it and made a typo (which i have now corrected. Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: Did you import the Foundation framework? Your error message says it is only a forward declaration which means it isn't finding the implementation of that class.

Comment: You got it. I think the fact that auto-complete was kicking in threw me off. Thanks!

Comment: OK now i'm even more confused... I had #import "<Foundation/Foundation.h>" which made the error go away but then when i tried to build i realized it should be <> or "" but not both and the error has returned :(

Comment: Could you post the full code? What error has returned, the same one?

Comment: Same 2 errors. I literally created a brand new "single view application" added the #import line right below #import "ViewController.h" and then added the troublesome line in viewDidLoad{}

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned NSHost is not available in iPhone, depends on what you need it for you could bypass it by using this sample code by apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1652/_index.html