# iOS Programmatically find IP Address

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ip-address

Is there a way to programmatically find the IP address of an iOS device? I tried the following

```
NSString* myIPAddress = [[NSHost currentHost] address];
```

but it seems like its giving me a IP v6 address.

Comment: You are aware that `NSHost` is private and your app will not be accepted to the App Store if you use it, right?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072989/iphone-ipad-how-to-get-my-ip-address-programmatically

Comment: @edt1591: NSHost is documented: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHost_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @rokjarc That's for Mac, the OP is talking about iOS.

Comment: @edt1591: a big oops from my side.

Comment: there is some useful info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434192/alternatives-to-nshost-in-iphone-app

Comment: This question has been asked several times. Try to search.