# iOS getifaddrs returns error 6 (Device not configured)

Tags: ios, c, network-programming, ip-address

## Update

Figured it out, and as expected it was a rather dumb mistake on my side. The problem was that an external project I recently added delivered its own version of `getifaddr.c` and my code was therefore including the wrong file.

A **"quick fix"** for this is to go into the project settings in XCode, then to your Build phases and then remove `getifaddr.c`/`getifaddr.h` from the "Compile Sources" phase. If you have a "Headers" phase, remove them there as well.

Depending on your project there might be a more elaborate solution, I've created another question to find out if there is: [XCode include system file instead of local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484141/xcode-include-system-file-instead-of-local-file)

---

## Original Question

I have a method in one of my iOS projects that returns the IP(s) of the network interfaces of the device. This has been working good so far, but I recently noticed that the method doesn't return any IPs anymore and instead `getifaddrs()` returns error 6 (Device not configured).

This happens on multiple devices and on iOS7 and iOS8, so its not a device-issue. I suppose it must be some code change I made, but the method in question was never changed so I can't see how this could happen. Since I don't know exactly when this error first occurred, I can't really pinpoint it to a specific code change.

The method in question:

```
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

/* Thanks to
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434192/alternatives-to-nshost-in-iphone-app and
http://zachwaugh.me/posts/programmatically-retrieving-ip-address-of-iphone/
*/
+ (NSArray *)deviceInterfaceAddresses
{
    struct ifaddrs *interfaces = NULL;
    struct ifaddrs *temp_addr = NULL;
    int success = -1;

    NSMutableArray *ips = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];

    // retrieve the current interfaces - returns 0 on success
    success = getifaddrs(&interfaces);
    if (success == 0)
    {
        while (temp_addr != NULL) 
        {
            NSString *interfaceName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name];
            if (temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET && ([interfaceName hasPrefix:@"en"] || [interfaceName hasPrefix:@"bridge"]))
            {
                //Get NSString from C String
                NSString *ip = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr)];
                if ([ip hasPrefix:@"0."] == NO && [ip hasPrefix:@"127."] == NO && [ip hasPrefix:@"255."] == NO)
                {
                    [ips addObject:ip];
                }
            }


            temp_addr = temp_addr->ifa_next;
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error getting IPs: %@ (%d)", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:strerror(errno)], errno);
    }

    // Free memory
    freeifaddrs(interfaces);

    //Remove duplicates
    NSMutableArray *finalIps = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[ips count]];
    for (NSString *ip in ips)
    {
        if (![finalIps containsObject:ip]) [finalIps addObject:ip];
    }

    return finalIps;
}
```

Comment: is it failing only when on cellular or when on Wi-Fi too?

Comment: It fails on both, unfortunately

Comment: Long shot, but try moving the include for ifaddrs.h to the bottom of the includes. There is a note in the man page indicating it should come last depending on the other includes you have. It must be something interfering with the function as I use this all the time.

Comment: figured it out, see my update

Comment: Hi blackWolf, I am getting same problem,  I have seen your update but i didn't get how to solve this problem, Could you tell me how to resolve step by step, please ?

Comment: see my post edit, I tried to explain what I did